# Android app bug when I test my app without plugging the cable to android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, testing

I developed an android application that is connected with a firestore database. The purpose is to schedule sales operations for stock, clients and more. Since I finished the project, I started to test it in a real environment and the app crashed. So, I plugged it into Android studio in order to view the problem, but when my device was plugged in, it did not crash! So, I couldn't figure out the problem. :(

Can anyone help me, please? Thank you :)

Comment: If you plug the device directly after the crash, the logs are still there

Comment: Also, you can debug over wifi (google for details).

Comment: Hello my friend, thank you for the answer, I've tried to download a logcat app but it told me that I need to give permissions in order to access to the logcats. I quited this option and now i'm trying to add ACRA report bug to my app and it's a little bit difficult for me, can you help me please ?

Comment: In my experience, I had a similar bug if I had a problem with asynchronous code. Adding breakpoints slows program and behaves differently. Are there any breakpoints?

Comment: Hello, Sorry for late !

Comment: Hello, Sorry for late ! the problem that I have concerns crashes without plugging the cable, for exemple i'm outside and I start to use the app and then when I switch between activities I have bug that redirects me to my HomeActivity that comes after my LoginActivity. I'm using firestore to share data with another app built with netbeans.

Comment: My supposition is that the problem is on the listening thread of send/reception of firestore because, the program accesses to the activity sometimes before the receiving of data but I'm not sure. So, I tried to implement ACRA Bug report in order to know exactly what is the error but it doesn't work too. I'm in a deadlock.